# psql client failing to import dump file - the system cannot find the specified file

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm attempting to import an SQL dump in PgAdmin 4 using the psql client - However the error message returned is - The system cannnot find the file specified.

Here is a screenshot of my psql client -

[image]

The file films.sql is currently stored on my desktop, but I suspect the default location that the psql client accesses is not my desktop? Is there anyway to set the location that the client looks in order to resolve this?

The file SQL is viewable here: https://github.com/datacamp/courses-intro-to-sql/tree/master/datasets

I simply want to get the database on my local machine so that I don't need to store queries in an online learning platform. It would be best if this database is available locally to query and practice on.

I've attempted to execute the whole SQL file as a query on the films database but this does not seem to be working either and returns 'Asynchronous query execution/operation underway.
Query returned successfully in 388 msec.' - However it seems to be the case that the Asynchronous query never completes when I refresh the database.

Please can someone help?

[image]

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just give the path to your file:

```
psql -d my_database -f /path/to/the/file.sql

psql -d my_database -f C:/path/to/the/file.sql
```

Depending on whether you are on a unix/linux machine or Windows.

Oh, and if you aren't familiar with file paths you may want to take a step back and become more familiar with general computer terminology before diving into a RDBMS. Your learning will be much easier if you have a solid foundation to build upon.

Comment: Still not working with this solution. Have added new screenshot. Please view when you get chance.

Comment: That screenshot shows that you aren't typing into a command line. It appears to be prompting you for individual values. I would strongly suggest becoming more familiar with basic computer operation before worrying about RDBMS management.

Comment: To further extend @RichardHuxton's answer, you should execute 'cmd' first to start a command line interpreter and then call the psql to issue the required command.

Comment: I'm typing into the psql Shell which I thought would be able to execute these commands - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE - I am familiar with basic computer operation and the command line, I'm just confused as to why the psql client is behaving like this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this question might be moot for the asker at this point, but for anyone else stumbling upon it like I did: the interactive connection info prompts are provided by a batch script (in Windows, I'd guess there's an analogous shell script for Unix) called `runpsql.bat`, which then just passes your inputs as commandline arguments to the `psql.exe` executable. I was getting this error because I had migrated my Postgres installation and the batch script was calling a nonexistent path for `psql.exe`, hence `The system cannot find the file specified`. I edited `runpsql.bat` to point to the correct location of `psql.exe` and that resolved the issue. So for OP, I would look into PgAdmin4 and see where it's (presumably) calling `runpsql.bat`, then make sure that that calls `psql.exe` with the correct path.